# A tale of 2 divs: 1 with fixed width, the other is percent - not quite filling area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple nested div structure:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
   <div id="divInfo" style="float:left;width:445px;height:100%;position:relative;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden">
      ... some divs and a table in here ...
   </div>
   <div id="divMap" style="float:left;width:75%;position:relative">
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="55" style="position:absolute; width:575px;top:5px; left:5px; z-index:10">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`<div id="map-canvas"></div>` contains the actual google map.

This div structure generates 2 side-by-side divs that [are supposed to] fill the entire page. `divInfo` behaves well and fills up exactly 445px of horizontal space, down to the bottom of the screen.

The problem is that I need `divMap` to fill the entire remainder of the outer container div and I can't make it quite do that. As it stands, it fills about 95%. You can see that I have `divMap` set to a width of 75%. If I increase that the slightest bit, the entire map disappears and all I see is the background image that covers the entire outer div. This window will be all different sizes for different users and I just need the left div to take up 445px of width, and the right div to take up ALL remaining screen space regardless of how large the screen is, with no gaps. I need it to stretch and fill every pixel of width and height. The height already works fine, it fills all height. But the width leaves that little gap, and the moment I try to increase the width by too much, the map disappears.

I am sure it's wrong to set a % width on `divMap`, but I don't know how else to do it. Setting an absolute width would certainly be wrong as well.

Note: The `map-canvas` div seems to completely fill `divMap`, but it seems that `divMap` is not behaving and filling all remaining area on the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stop floating the right one, and don’t give it a width …

Comment: CBroe, when I remove the float and the width, the entire google map (map-canvas inside divMap) disappears.